# Spring Boot keycloak and basic authentication together in the same project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, keycloak

I have an issue with Spring Boot security. What I want is to have two different authentication for the same project at the same time in Spring Boot. The one is SSO (keycloak authentication) for all path except '/download/export/*'  , the other one is Spring Boot basic authentication.
Here is my configuration file:

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurityp 
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class DownloadableExportFilesSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
            .antMatcher("/download/export/test")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER1")
            .and()
            .httpBasic();    }

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password1").roles("USER1");
}
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public static class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy()
{
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    super.configure(http);
    http
            .regexMatcher("^(?!.*/download/export/test)")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "SUPER_ADMIN")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/bye");

}
}
```

The problem with above code is the following:
If I request url '/download/export/test', than it asks me the username/password (Basic authentication). After successful login it asks me again for username/password (but this time keycloak authentication) , even if the requested url is excluded from SecurityConfig (Keycloak Adapter).

It gives me only a warning:

```
2016-06-20 16:31:28.771  WARN 6872 --- [nio-8087-exec-6] o.k.a.s.token.SpringSecurityTokenStore   : Expected a KeycloakAuthenticationToken, but found org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@3fb541cc: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@36ebcb: Username: user; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER1; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 4C1BD3EA1FD7F50477548DEC4B5B5162; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER1
```

Do you have any ideas how to use keycloak and basic authentication together?

Many many thanks!
Carlo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SpringBoot multiple authentication adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921103/springboot-multiple-authentication-adapter)

Comment: Is there any new information on this problem? Have you solved it?

Answer (score 33):

### Problem explanation

The problem you're having is that `KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java` **intercepts every request with HTTP Authorization header**. If your request is not authenticated with Keycloak (Even if you're authenticated with any other authentication provider! - in your case with basic authentication) you'll **always** either be redirected to Keycloak's login page (in your case) or get 401 Unauthorized (if your Keycloak client in `keycloak.json` is configured to bearer-only).

By default `KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java` is invoked if request matches `KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.DEFAULT_REQUEST_MATCHER`:

```
public static final RequestMatcher DEFAULT_REQUEST_MATCHER =
    new OrRequestMatcher(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher(DEFAULT_LOGIN_URL),
            new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER),
            new QueryParamPresenceRequestMatcher(OAuth2Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN)
    );
```

This means that any request that matches DEFAULT_LOGIN_URL (*/sso/login*) **OR** contains Authorization HTTP header (in your case) **OR** has *access_token* as query parameter, will be processed by `KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java`.

That's why you have to replace `RequestHeaderRequestMatcher(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER)` with your own implementation that will skip invocation of `KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java` when request is authenticated with basic authentication.

### Solution

Below is a full solution that enables you to use both Basic authentication and Keycloak authentication simultaneously on the same paths. Pay special attention to **IgnoreKeycloakProcessingFilterRequestMatcher** implementation which is replacing default *RequestHeaderRequestMatcher*. This matcher will match only requests containing Authorization HTTP header which value is not prefixed with `"Basic "`.

In example below, user with role `TESTER` can access `/download/export/test` while all other paths are available to users with `ADMIN` or `SUPER_ADMIN` roles (which I assume, in your case, are accounts on Keycloak server).

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("tester")
                .password("testerPassword")
                .roles("TESTER");
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        RequestMatcher requestMatcher =
                new OrRequestMatcher(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher(DEFAULT_LOGIN_URL),
                        new QueryParamPresenceRequestMatcher(OAuth2Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN),
                        // We're providing our own authorization header matcher
                        new IgnoreKeycloakProcessingFilterRequestMatcher()
                );
        return new KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authenticationManagerBean(), requestMatcher);
    }

    // Matches request with Authorization header which value doesn't start with "Basic " prefix
    private class IgnoreKeycloakProcessingFilterRequestMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
        IgnoreKeycloakProcessingFilterRequestMatcher() {
        }

        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String authorizationHeaderValue = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            return authorizationHeaderValue != null && !authorizationHeaderValue.startsWith("Basic ");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/download/export/test")
                .hasRole("TESTER")
                .anyRequest()
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "SUPER_ADMIN")
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but which version of keycloak-spring-security-adapter are you using ?

Comment: This example is for version 3.4.3.Final.

Comment: With spring-boot 2.3.0, I get this error, The bean 'httpSessionManager', defined in class path resource [net/ifao/companion/ccbd/config/KeycloakSecurityConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/wjose/.m2/repository/org/keycloak/keycloak-spring-security-adapter/5.0.0/keycloak-spring-security-adapter-5.0.0.jar!/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/management/HttpSessionManager.class] and overriding is disabled.

Comment: use the matching version of keycloak if you are using spring-boot 2.3.0. Then u need to use 6.0.1 onwards
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-spring-boot-starter/6.0.1

Comment: Great solution thanks :) I have an optimisation for it which is more future version compatible: 
        RequestMatcher requestMatcher =
                new AndRequestMatcher(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.DEFAULT_REQUEST_MATCHER,
                        // We're providing our own authorization header matcher
                        new IgnoreKeycloakProcessingForBasicAuthenticationFilterRequestMatcher()
                );

Comment: This doesn't work for me, unless I disable the enforcer for that path but then it doesn't display Spring's login page for basic auth. I have this settings:
`http.
                authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider())
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(oAuth2AuthenticationSettings.getActuatorNonProtectedUrlPattern()).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(oAuth2AuthenticationSettings.getActuatorPrefix() + "/**").hasRole("ACTUATOR_USER")
                .and().httpBasic();`

Comment: can you please check my settings (previous comment) and see if I made any mistake?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by configuring an exception on KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter for the path:

```
...
@Configuration
@Order(2)
static class KeyCloakSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
            authenticationManagerBean()
            , new AndRequestMatcher(
               KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.DEFAULT_REQUEST_MATCHER,
               new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(YOUR_BASIC_AUTHD_PATH))));
    filter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());
    return filter;
}
```